# How to create a text file containing layer names in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, table-of-contents, group-layer

My QGIS ToC contains layer groups and some layers that do not belong to any group.

I would like to create a text file containing the name of those layers that do not belong to any group.

Is there an automated way to do it?

Comment: Could you please expand a bit your question? What would you like the `txt` file to contain?

Comment: my excuses,I work with many layers (100+) some of them I grouped together. Those that I could not group someone else need to have a look at. For this reason I would like the txt file to contain the names of those layers I did not group. Basically just a list. I could do this manually but hope there is another way to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that from the QGIS Python console. Follow this workflow:

1. Open the QGIS Python console
2. Adjust the following line to match the path of your text file and copy the whole line to the QGIS Python console:

   ```py
   textFilePath = '/tmp/non_grouped_layers.txt'
   ```

   *As you can see, in the example above, I want to create a text file named 'non_grouped_layers.txt' in the folder `/tmp/`, I'm on a GNU/Linux machine.*
3. Press Enter.
4. Copy the following code snippet to your QGIS Python console and, after that, press Enter a couple of times:

   ```py
   # Get a reference of the layer tree
   root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
   tree = root.children()

   # Get names of non-grouped layers
   nonGrouped = []
   for node in tree:
       if isinstance( node, QgsLayerTreeLayer ):
           nonGrouped.append( node.layerName() )

   #Save the nonGrouped list as text file
   f = open( textFilePath, 'wt')
   f.write( '\n'.join( nonGrouped ) )
   f.close()
   ```

You should now have your text file with the list of non-grouped layers.

---

In the screenshot you can see my QGIS ToC arrangement and the text file I get from running the code snippet.

[image]

If you face troubles, tell me.

Comment: On trying this in QGIS3 console I get the following error -is there some difference in running this line? 

f = open( textFilePath, 'wt')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<input>", line 4
    f = open( textFilePath, 'wt')
    ^

Comment: `node.layerName()` has changed in QGIS 3, it should be now `node.name()`. Other than that, everything should work. Just tested it and it runs smoothly.